# Проблема с записью звука Android (MediaRecorder)

Tags: java, android, аудио, mediarecorder

Повесил событие записи на одну кнопку и обрабатываю с помощью setOnTouchListener (на ACTION_DOWN (start) и на ACTION_UP (stop). Если я нажимаю и **удерживаю** кнопку, после чего отпускаю - все в порядке. Но если я нажимаю и **сразу же** отпускаю, программа вылетает...
Обработчик события:

```
btnEnter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                //Получение доступа для использования микрофона

                if(checkPermissionFromDevice()){
                    FILE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                            getAbsolutePath() + "/" + UUID.randomUUID().
                            toString() + "_audio_record.3gp";

                    MEDIA_RECORDER = new MediaRecorder();
                    MEDIA_RECORDER.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    MEDIA_RECORDER.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    MEDIA_RECORDER.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                    MEDIA_RECORDER.setOutputFile(FILE_NAME);

                    try {
                        MEDIA_RECORDER.prepare();
                        MEDIA_RECORDER.start();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    requestPermission();
                }
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(MEDIA_RECORDER != null) MEDIA_RECORDER.stop();
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

Как я понял, ругается на метод **stop:**

```
2018-12-26 11:56:45.410 5399-5399/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.username.example, PID: 5399
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
    at com.example.username.example.MainActivity$2.onTouch(MainActivity.java:158)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11772)
```

### Ошибка была решена использованием задержки, как написал [Andrew Goroshko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/238742/andrew-goroshko), или округлением метода **stop** блоком *try-catch*.

Comment: а что в логах показывает? на какую строку указывает?

Comment: Добавил LogCat в описание. Но там довольно много "исключений", я посчитал, что логичной причиной может быть именно эта ошибка. Может метод start, при быстром нажатии и отпускании, не успевает обрабатывать ситуацию, а тут stop уже завершает поток записи...

Comment: а строка с номером 158 что из себя представляет?

Comment: } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        if(MEDIA_RECORDER != null) MEDIA_RECORDER.stop();
} ---> **строка №158** (Завершающая скобка данного блока)

Comment: можно попробовать в handler запихнуть вашу остановку и запуск, может поможет) проблема вообще возникает при клике

Comment: При быстром клике. Нажал и сразу отпустил. А если нажать, подержать, звук запишется, и отпустить - всё замечательно работает. В момент быстрого нажатия и отпускания, получается, что запись ещё не началась, а мы уже останавливаем. Как будто не хватает задержки...

Comment: ну можно добавить задержку)) сейчас отправлю ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример задержки:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               останавливаем запись через 4 секунды
            }
        }, 4000);
```

надеюсь это поможет в решении вашей проблемы. Если что-то будет не понятно, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте.

Comment: Проблема решилась задержкой, но меня больше волнует вопрос, не есть ли данное решение "костылём", и должно ли так быть на самом деле)) Но вам спасибо))

Comment: думаю что данное решение не есть костылем, потому что при некоторых действиях необходимо завершить все процессы перед выполнением какой-то функции. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: Чисто случайно убрал задержку, и оставил метод **stop** в блоке *try-catch*, ошибка так же пропала... Не мог не поделиться находкой))